# iOS Material Components MDCButton change Text color when button is pressed

Tags: ios, material-design, material-components, material-components-ios

I am using an MDCButton with a storyboard, how can I set the text color when the button is pressed (or in a highlighted state). I am using `MDCSemanticColorScheme` to set the color scheme of the button. Basically I need to contrast the titleColor with the inkColor.

Code of the button being initialised from Storyboard : -

```
import UIKit
import MaterialComponents

class LightButton: MDCButton {

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    MDCButtonColorThemer.applySemanticColorScheme(Theme.lightColorScheme(), to: self)
    inkColor = Color.brandLightColor
  }

}
```

Comment: Same problem here